# Test whether "jimbovi" is a color name in R or not

Tags: r, colors

`colors()` in R provides a list of 657 color names built into R. I was wondering how I could search this list of colors to find out whether a color name that I have in my mind is included in this list or not?

For example, I need a test that would return `FALSE` if I test:

`is "jimbovi" part of the colors()`. Also, the test would say `TRUE` if I test:

`is "yellow" part of the colors()`.

Comment: color = 'jimbovi';sum(colors() == color) > 0 ; color2 = 'yellow';sum(colors() == color2) > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> "jimbovi" %in% colors()
[1] FALSE
> "yellow" %in% colors()
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I provide a color number say `-1e16` how can I test weather  this number represents a color number in R or not. For example if I provide `-1e16` the test will say `FALSE`, but if I provide `20` the test provide `TRUE`?